# A constant declared in my main module is not available in other modules/services?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I have a constant declared on my main module that links the other modules together in angular:

```
.constant('FIREBASE_URL', 'https://demo.firebaseio.com')
```

Unfortunately, I can't seem to pass it in to other controllers and services of other modules. Is there a way around this or something I am missing?

Edit with more detail:

```
//add the constant to the main module
    angular.module('app', [
          'home',
          'subscribe'
        ])
        .config(config)
        .run(run)
        .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl)
        .value('version', '1.0.1')
        .constant('FIREBASE_URL', 'https://talllly.firebaseio.com')
        });
      });

angular
        .module('subscribe')
        .factory('Subscribe', Subscribe);

    function Subscribe($firebase, FIREBASE_URL) {
        var Subscriptions = {
            subscribeStatus: subscribeStatus, //try to use FIREBASE_URL in this function
            loginStatus : loginStatus
        };
```

Comment: You have to setup your modules to receive FIREBASE_URL as a dependency. `.module('ctrl1', ['FIREBASE_URL', function(fbase){ .. }])`.

Comment: We can't tell what you're doing wrong, until you show how you're trying to use that constant. An example from one of my apps: `app.constant('FBURL', "https://trenches.firebaseio.com/");` and `app.controller("TrenchesCtrl", function($scope, FBURL, $firebase) {`. https://trenches.firebaseapp.com/app.js

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I added more detail in the edit above. Can constants be injected into services? If they are injected into the controller should they not also be injected into the service maybe?

Comment: Constants can be injected into services. If you check the app.js linked above, you can find an example of that too. But the snippet you added does not define a service `function Subscribe` is a regular function and Angular will not inject anything into it. Services are defined with `app.factory`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I added some additional details to show how I have that service setup. Should I make a plnkr?

Comment: Sure. Or try to create a runnable code snippet in your question. Important thing is to remove anything that is not relevant to your problem, in this case that probably means you can do without Firebase (as I suspect you'll have the same problem injecting *any* constant). A first try might be to use an anonymous function for your service like the services in my linked app.js. I'm not used to seeing Angular services defined as regular JavaScript functions and there is probably a good reason for that.